# The way to use jQuery method for the element of current page in jQueryMobile

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

This is kind of silly and newbie question though,
How would you use jQuery for current page of Jquery mobile which is actually just a `Div` element in the whole html file.
I am currently using `$("#" + $.mobile.activePage.attr("id"))` to select the current page though,is there any better way to do the same?

InAddition I'd be glad if you suggest the way to select its footer/header elements directly.

Thanks for your answer.

Comment: What is your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. **jQuery Mobile <= 1.3**

   Use `$.mobile.activePage` which returns a DOM collection.

   ```
   var activePage   = $.mobile.activePage,
       activePageID = activePage[0].id,
       header       = $(".ui-header", activePage), /* or [data-role=header] */ 
       footer       = $(".ui-footer", activePage); /* or [data-role=footer] */
   ```
2. **jQuery Mobile >= 1.4**

   Use `$.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("getActivePage")`.

   ```
   var activePage   = $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("getActivePage"),
       activePageID = activePage[0].id,
       header       = $(".ui-header", activePage), /* or [data-role=header] */ 
       footer       = $(".ui-footer", activePage); /* or [data-role=footer] */
   ```

Answer (score 0):

`$('.ui-page-active').attr('id')` will do the same for selecting current page in jqueymobile